# Import compiled code into C/C++ source code for microcontroller

Tags: dll, import, embedded, microcontroller

We'd like to offer a compiled library that implement a protocol layer to be imported into C/C++ source code project for microcontrollers. And eventually expose a sort of compiled function to the source code project. let's say a sort of "dll". Is there any know technique to realize something of similar?

Comment: Pro-tip: your question was only viewed 3 times in half an hour.  A question title with spelling mistakes and all capitals don't invite anybody to have a look.  Justifiably, the answer is "Yes".

Comment: The "compiled function" is intended to be run on a different CPU? Is that a question about including a binary firmware in a DLL?

Comment: Thank you hans for your tips. Manuell, the "compiled function" or class is to be given to third parts to let these include the relative function to their source code without having a clear view of the original source code. A way to protect the development effort.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to provide functions via a library, generally in the microcontroller/embedded realm it quickly becomes impractical.

Each microcontroller core will have a unique instruction set.  Further, micros from the same family may have a variety of extensions which are either supported or not...  So you're left with providing a library file for each individual microcontroller (from each vendor) that you'd like to support.

But...

In my experience, calling conventions between compilers are not the same.  So a library compiled by one toolchain will not be able to be linked to object files created by another toolchain.

That leads you to then provide a library for each individual micro from each vendor for each toolchain someone might use.  Ick.  Oh, and don't rely on an OS calls either, as you don't know what you'll be linked with...

A more conventional approach is to use the same approach RTOS vendors tend to use: provide the source, and protect your IP with licensing terms.  The reality is that if your end users want to, they can step through the assembly and figure out exactly what is happening, so you're not hiding your implementation that carefully anyway.

Comment: Dear Ross, thank you for sharing your experience and tips. Whan you are a startup you have few means to protect your IPRs; therefore, our idea was something like this: offer at beginning this layer for a single uC/compiler. Since the product is for a B2B market clients are middle or big. Thus, if one of them would like to use a different uC, quantities could justify an effort of our for a porting action. At the same time we where thinking to give the "binary library" in a encrypted version to be stored in blinded section of the fw flash.

Comment: And use a sort of bootloader to decrypt by the mean of an external software to give the proper keys.

Comment: If the processor can run it, it has to be decrypted, and at that point the assembly code can be viewed.  You're being overprotective of your code to the point it becomes no longer salable, which defeats the purpose.  Besides, your middle to large B2B clients are probably the safest market to sell into with the source license approach, as they have assets that mean they won't want to risk a lawsuit by stealing your IP.